# php mysql display the records in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing an availability system. I need to display the records in a table.

My system is basically about real estate which tracks if a property is available or not. Sample is I have 20 floors in condominium each floor has 10 units so I need to loop the number of floors and also display each unit under a specific floor.

`1st flr  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 
2nd flr  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <?php
                for($i=0; $row3 = $stmt3->fetch(); $i++){
                  $floor = $row3['floor'];
            ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $floor; ?></td>
            <?php
                for($i=0; $row4 = $stmt4->fetch(); $i++){
                  $unit_code = $row4['unit_code'];
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $unit_code; ?></td>
            <?php 
              }
            ?>

          </tr>
          <?php 
            }
          ?>
        </table>
```

But it's just display all the records in the first floor.

This is what actually happened:

```
1st flr| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 
2nd flr
```

What could be the correct way to achieve my needs? Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

```
  $stmt3 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT floor
  FROM tblunitsmaster 
  WHERE project_code = :code" );
  $stmt3->execute(array(':code' => $code));


  $stmt4 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT unit_code
  FROM tblunitsmaster 
  WHERE project_code = :code
  AND floor = :floor
  AND sub_project_code = 'SUB-AX0001'" );
```

Comment: You need to add your db structure and the sql calls you're making.

Comment: This is happening because your inner loop is getting executed first i.e. all your `unit_code` is printed before the `floor` can change. One way to solve this is to change your query to fetch `unit_code` by `floor`.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger can you provide sample query of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have already solved it, but [Satish Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931841/satish-sharma) code has a typo on line 6. The line should be

```
$floor = $row3['floor'];
```

This will solve your problem. I really should comment on the answer but don't have enough points.

Updated code below

**UPDATE:**
Latest update for each floor with its own set of units.

```
<?php
$code = 'so';
$stmt3 = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT floor
FROM tblunitsmaster 
WHERE project_code = :code" );
$stmt3->execute(array(':code' => $code));


$stmt4 = $pdo2->prepare( "SELECT unit_code
FROM tblunitsmaster 
WHERE project_code = :code
AND floor = :floor
AND sub_project_code = 'SUB-AX0001'" );

?>
<table border="1px" class="table table-bordered">
    <?php
    $rows3 = $stmt3->fetchAll();

    foreach ($rows3 as $row3) {
        $floor = $row3['floor'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $floor; ?></td>
            <?php
            $stmt4->execute(array(':code' => $code, ':floor' => $floor));
            $rows4 = $stmt4->fetchAll();            
            foreach ($rows4 as $row4) {
                $unit_code = $row4['unit_code'];
                ?>
                <td><?php echo $unit_code; ?></td>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

OUTPUT:

```
1st flr 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2nd flr 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
3rd flr 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

Comment: Yes I updated his code, but I'm still not  getting the correct records displayed in each floor

Comment: @Dunkey - It worked for me. Of course I have used my own SQL, but I guessed all floors will have the same units (say 1-10). If this is not the case then the logic is wrong, let me know. I have posted the whole code I worked on. Please see if you can work with this. Also you may share the output you got from this code with your own SQL.

Comment: Can we chat in the chatroom I had with Satish?

Comment: Okay I'll just give you the query I have. My stmt4 needs to $stmt4 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT unit_code
                          FROM tblunitsmaster 
                          WHERE project_code = :code
                          AND floor = :floor
                          AND sub_project_code = 'SUB-AX0001'" );

Comment: I see! In this SQL, the units may differ for each floor. So, the logic will be a little different. We will execute stmt4 inside the foreach loop of every floor. I am now updating my post with a working code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might solve your problem:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<?php
    $stmt3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `floor` FROM `tblunitsmaster` WHERE `project_code` = :code")->execute(array(':code' => $code))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt4 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `unit_code` FROM `tblunitsmaster` WHERE `project_code` = :code AND `floor` = :floor AND `sub_project_code` = 'SUB-AX0001");

    foreach ($stmt3 as $row3){
        $floor = $row3['floor'];

        echo '<tr></td>'.$floor.'</td>';

        if ($stmt4->execute(array(':code' => $code, ':floor' => $floor))){
            foreach ($stmt4->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row4){
                echo '<td>'.$row4['unit_code'].'</td>';
            }
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset your result for `$stmt4-`

try this

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <?php
                $rows3 = $stmt3->fetchAll();
                $rows4 = $stmt4->fetchAll();
                foreach($rows3 as $row3){
                  $floor = $row['floor'];
            ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $floor; ?></td>
            <?php
                foreach($rows4 as $row4){
                  $unit_code = $row4['unit_code'];
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $unit_code; ?></td>
            <?php 
              }

            ?>

          </tr>
          <?php 
            }
          ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: What is the data_seek(0) ?

Comment: Yes but I'm getting error, Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::data_seek() on line 171, Line 171 is: $stmt4->data_seek(0); // use this to reseet your result

Comment: I'm getting this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' on line 161

Comment: what is on your line no 161

Comment: ok i got that you need to use `foreach` instead of `for`. i have updated it. try now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48341/discussion-between-dunkey-and-satish-sharma)

Comment: I'm getting the wrong records, the floor numbers didn't display and also all units are displayed

Answer (score 0):

`for($i=0; $row3 = $stmt3->fetch(); $i++)`

What is in $stmt3?

I think you are using the [FOR loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) wrong. The second part, your `$row3 = $stmt3->fetch()`, should be an evaluation and not a setting of a variable.

You are probably looking for something like:

`for($i=0; $stmt3->fetch() <> null; $i++){
$row3 = $stmt3->fetch()`

Same for the second FOR loop.

I could be a little wrong with the answer.

Comment: I added the stmt3 in my post.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not a good idea to put a sql call in a loop. Instead, structure your db call to group the data properly - "select floor, condo_unit group by floor, condo_unit". Then, iterate through the result set.